# Azure website disable FREB in deployment slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to clean up my Event logs which show lots of identical errors

[image: event log errors]

Event ID [2284 seems to be related to FREB](https://forums.iis.net/t/1158660.aspx?Failed%20Request%20Tracing%20Event%202284), so when Anil (see link) says

> " if you have multiple apps running under multiple app-pools, they
>   will each try to use the next filename in sequence and hence fail "

it made me wonder if the different staging slots were causing a conflict - which led me to want to try and turn off FREB for non-Production slots (with a sticky app setting slot maybe) to see if that stops all these log entries.

Is there a way to disable FREB on a per-slot basis?

edit: I can see there is a CLI command (-F) but I'm not sure how to bind this to the staging slot, permanently.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this, select the targeted deployment slot in azure portal. a setting blade opens, look for diagnostics logs and then you should be able to enable/disable required logging settings.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But won't the disabled FREB then remain disabled when Staging is swapped with Live (ie: no more live FREB, only staging)? I thought that was the case? I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: swapping with production only swap the app binaries but not configurations. you set your production settings as you like.

Comment: today I started with Stage:Freb Off, Production: Freb On. I then swapped. The result is now Stage:Freb On, Production: Freb Off. I am just using the portal to swap. How do you do it so the logging settings are 'slot sticky' ?

Comment: @NeilThompson sorry for the late reply, under settings in app service there is a check box called "Slot setting" which means if you checked it, it leads to that settings applies only on the current slot, if not checked i would be copied over with any swap operation. hope this helps.

Comment: I can see the slot setting option for the available AppSettings, but I can't seem to find the option to make FREB slot sticky. Can you post a picture?